# Test automation - WinAppDriver impossible to interact for more than 1 second with telerik RadComboBox

Tags: combobox, automated-tests, telerik, winappdriver

I'm using WinAppDriver and Appium to automate a desktop app tests.
I'm facing an issue when the automated testing robot is clicking on a wpf telerik radcombobox.
The drop-down list is well displayed during less than 1s and then it closed itself preventing the robot to select an item only accessible through the drop-down list running the below code snippet :

[C#]

```
Using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.windows;
Using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;

//Code to launch the driver

//Get the telerik RadComboBox
WindowsElement myRadComboBox = myWindowsDriver.FindElementByAccessibilityId("ComboBox_Automation_Id");

Actions actionsToInteractWithComboBox = new Actions(myWindowsDriver);

actionsToInteractWithComboBox.MoveToElement.Click(myRadComboBox);
actionsToInteractWithComboBox.Perform();
```

Let's say the drop-down list includes 3 items "Al", "Ar" and "Em" and 1st is Al displayed by default in the textbox.
The same behavior happens when trying to send keys to display "Ar". I first manually clear "Al" from the textbox and then the robot performed a click and sent "Ar" to the combo but "Al" is displayed meaning "A" is well written but "r" is never received by the combobox:

```
actionsToInteractWithComboBox.Click(myRadComboBox).SendKeys("Ar");
actionsToInteractWithComboBox.Perform();
```

I confirm this behavior by clearing manually again "Al" and this time the robot send "E" and I was able to display "Em":

```
actionsToInteractWithComboBox.MoveToElement.Click(myRadComboBox).SendKeys("E");
actionsToInteractWithComboBox.Perform();
```

This happens whatever is the comboBox mode "editable" or "not editable". With editable when clicking inside the combobox the time is not enough sufficient to display the drop-down list while with the not editable one the robot has just the time to display it before it closes immediately.

[RadComboBox modes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIK3V.png)

It seems that after a short while the combobox goes into a state or triggers an event that prevents it from receiving further commands from the winAppDriver. It is like a double click is performed. I suppose the issue is with the combobox itself and not the WinAppDriver?
However I don't know whether it comes from how it is coded or from the telerik component itself. Here's the code of the combobox:

```
         <Controls:RadComboBox x:Name="ComboTitle" DisplayMode="{Binding DisplayModeIdentiteBloc}" Height="20" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ParentEntity.Individuals, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true}" ItemsSource="{Binding TitleLookup}" DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Key" SelectionChanged="ComboTitle_SelectionChanged" IsAdornable="True"/>
```

Note: Sending keys to a telerik textbox does not show this behavior.
I've also tried to move the cursor by location before clicking on the combobox with same result:

```
actionsToInteractWithComboBox.MoveToElement(myRadComboBox, myRadComboBox.Location.X, myRadComboBox.Location.Y);
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It's not an issue, I was using Actions the wrong way. Here is the C# code that is correct:

```
Actions actionsComboBox = new Actions(App_WinAppDriver);

WindowsElement comboBox = App_WinAppDriver.FindElementByAccessibilityId("comboBoxAutomationId");

/*MoveToElement in the example below is specific to a Telerik radComboBox
 *which must be given the offset of the button to click on it and display
 *the drop-down list. When the MoveToElement instruction is given an offset,
/*the reference is the upper left corner of the user control. Please see the link below.

int halfPixelWidthOfButton = 6;

actionsComboBox.MoveToElement(comboBox, comboBox.Size.Width - halfPixelWidthOfButton, comboBox.Size.Height / 2);
actionsComboBox.ClickAndHold();
actionsComboBox.Perform();
```

[Appium doc for MoveToElement](https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/commands/interactions/mouse/moveto/)

This code works both with Telerik RadComboBox and WPF ComboBox, the dropdown is displayed and remains opened with the click and hold command instead of a simple click as I did initially.